# How to get a checkbox value using custom adapter and listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am trying to get a checked value but it is not showing the value, I have implemented custom adapter there i am not getting how to update position

My code is..

```
   public Add_member_adapter(Context a, ArrayList<ItemsModel> d) {

        context = a;
        data = d;
        itemChecked = new boolean[data.size()];

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    public final Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(getCount() - position - 1);
    }

    public final long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView Name, UserId_Fk;
        CheckBox chkbox;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d("getview:", "position=" + position);
        vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_members_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.Name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            holder.UserId_Fk = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.CusId_Fk);
            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        }
        if (data.size() <= 0) {

            vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = (ItemsModel) data.get(position);

            holder.Name.setText(tempValues.getItemName().toString());
            holder.UserId_Fk.setText(tempValues.getUserId_Fk().toString());
            holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);



            holder.chkbox.setChecked(itemChecked[position]);

            holder.chkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            itemChecked[position] = isChecked;
                        }
                    });
        }
        return vi;
    }
```

and i am declaring List setOnItemClickListener another in activity

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                CheckBox checkbox = ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox));

                String Name = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();



            }

        });
```

Comment: you can use setOnCheckedChangeListener on checkbox

Comment: you already have position availble and you want to do some operation to element at that position on setOnClickListener right ? I suggested you to use setOnCheckedChangeListener instead of click listener. what exactly is the problem here. Can you be more clearer?

Comment: there is textview and checkbox. If i select 4th checkbox it should give a 4th position text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any clickable view inside a list view item will steal list view onItemClickListener click.

If you want to catch check event on your check boxes, you should use CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener instead of View.OnClickListener.

Since convertView on ListView is re-useable, you must aware that your data will not accurate. You must make a data set to hold your values that you want to keep.

This code is from your adapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("getview:", "position=" + position);
        vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_members_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.Name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            holder.UserId_Fk = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.CusId_Fk);
            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        }
        if (data.size() <= 0) {

            vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = (ItemsModel) data.get(position);

            holder.Name.setText(tempValues.getItemName().toString());
            holder.UserId_Fk.setText(tempValues.getUserId_Fk().toString());

            holder.chkbox.setChecked(checkedHolder[position]);

            holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    checkedHolder[position] = isChecked;
                }
            });
        }
        return vi;
    }

    public boolean[] checkedHolder;

    private void createCheckedHolder() {
        checkedHolder = new boolean[getCount()];
    }
```

Call createCheckedHolder on your adapter's constructor. And if you want to get the checked value, you can get from checkedHolder

From the checkedHolder, you can get the position of any items that selected by the user, then you can call below code from your activity

```
private ArrayList<String> getSelectedNames(){
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                if(adapter.checkedHolder[i]){
                    //get all name values that checked by user
                    names.get(i).add(yourDataSet.getItemName().toString());
                }
            }
return names
}
```

Comment: can u update list.setOnItemClickListener Its save my life

Comment: as i said, if you add any clickable view on your list items, your list.setOnItemClickListener will not work, because any clickable view will steal the click

Comment: for alternative, you can change your check box with image view, then you can change the image of that image view with image of disabled or enabled checkbox inside your list.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: another alternative, you can set android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" on your XML file for check box, and manually call ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox)).setChecked(!((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox)).getValue()); inside your list.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: 07-10 18:14:49.617: E/AndroidRuntime(23852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Add_members}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int abc.adapters.Add_member_adapter.getCount()' on a null object reference

Comment: you should make getCount() method on your adapter, and return your data length from there

Comment: Please check my adapter code and i am updated as per your code.

Comment: Please check my updated adapter code, i tried it but it is throwing null exception

Comment: Since you have declared itemChecked = new boolean[data.size()];, i think you don't need getCount anymore. And, why should you return 1 on your getCount method?

Comment: Ok can u update it in both side activity and adapter please it is eating my head

Comment: So, what you actually want to achieve? Are you want to get all of the selected items that user select or just get 1 item when user click on the list?

Comment: if he select three checkbox, three name should come like that if we check one check box that name should come

Comment: I have updated the code, put method getSelectedNames on your Activity. This should return your list of names

Comment: Please can u update my above code , both adapter and activity it will save my life

Comment: Dude, you should try it yourself. It's not that complicated. You should understand every single piece of your code and know how it will work. You can always put Log there or even debug your app to see how your code work. I think what i've posted is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

See my code. I am using this way for getting the checked item from listview :

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MovieVO>{

    Context context;
    List<MovieVO> movieList;
    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieVO> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        movieList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        TextView tvMovieName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieName);
        TextView tvRating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRating);
        TextView tvGenre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGenre);
        TextView tvYear = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvYear);
        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        CheckBox cbSelect = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbSelect);

        if(movieList.get(position).isSelected())
        {
            cbSelect.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            cbSelect.setChecked(false);
        }

        cbSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    movieList.get(position).setSelected(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    movieList.get(position).setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        });

        tvMovieName.setText(movieList.get(position).getName());
        tvRating.setText(movieList.get(position).getRating());
        tvGenre.setText(Arrays.toString(movieList.get(position).getGenre()).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        tvYear.setText(movieList.get(position).getYear());
        Picasso.with(context).load(movieList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(ivImage);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Here, i add the true or false value based on the item check and uncheck. When you want all selected value from list, then just iterate the list and check the true false value.