# Custom adapter's asynchronous behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I have created my own custom adapter class in my android app and I am calling it from one of my activity. I am adding some elements to the view from the adapter class and I need to access those variables from my activity class.

Now, ideally I would expect it to fill the view and then execute the further code in my activity class, but adapter class is taking some time to populate the view and in the meanwhile further code in my activity class is getting executed where no such elements have been added yet. 
How do I handle this situation? I come from a js background. Do we have something like promises in java?

According to the answers I have my changed my code to this:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    GridView grid;
    String text[] = {"Calendar","Uber","Weather","News","Youtube","Clock","Email","Maps","Twitter","Facebook"};
    String list_app_name[] = {"calendar","uber","weather","news","youtube","clock","email","maps","twitter","facebook"};
    String id_button[] = {"button_calendar","button_uber","button_weather","button_news","button_youtube","button_clock","button_email","button_maps","button_twitter","button_facebook"};
    int image[] = {R.drawable.social_icons1,R.drawable.social_icons2,R.drawable.social_icons3,R.drawable.social_icons4,
            R.drawable.social_icons5,R.drawable.social_icons6, R.drawable.social_icons7,R.drawable.social_icons8,
            R.drawable.social_icons9,R.drawable.social_icons10};
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //setting up the adapter for gridView
        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.simpleGrid);
        ImageAdapter ia = new ImageAdapter(this,image,text,id_button);
        grid.setAdapter(ia);

        ia.notifyDataSetChanged();

        try {
            initStateOfApps();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void initStateOfApps() throws JSONException {
        Log.d("here","here");
        ArrayList<String> list = getEnabledApps();
        Log.d("apps",list.toString());
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
            String app_name = list.get(i);

            ToggleButton button=null;
            if(app_name.equals("calendar")) {
                button = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.button_calendar);
                button.setChecked(true);
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

So what is happening is that I am creating some toggle buttons that are getting populated in the ImageAdapter class that I wrote.
Once the ImageAdapter is called, I call the `notifydatasetchanged()` on the adapter in order to update the view.
What I am doing inside the adapter is giving each of the toggle buttons some custom ID I wrote in `res/values/ids.xml`.
After using `setId` on each of the toggle buttons, I try using that ID in my `activity class` but it gives me `nullPointerException` in the `initStateOfApps()` where I am trying to change the state of button.

So even after using the `notifyDataSetChanged` it is still behaving the same.

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final int item_image[];
    private final String item_text[];
    private final String button_id[];
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int item_image[], String[] item_text,String[] button) {
        this.context = context;
        this.item_image = item_image;
        this.item_text = item_text;
        this.button_id = button;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from custom_gridview.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

            // set value into imageview
            final ImageView image = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            image.setImageResource(item_image[position]);

            // set value into textview
            TextView text = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            text.setText(item_text[position]);

            final ToggleButton button_ = (ToggleButton) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);

            if(position==0) {
                button_.setId(R.id.button_calendar);
                image.setId(R.id.image_calendar);
            } 


            button_.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked)
                {

                    if(context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(toggleButton.getId()).equals("button_calendar")) {
                        if(isChecked) {
                            try {
                                setStateOfApp("calendar","true");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, GoogleApp.class);
                            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,10);

                        } else {
                            try {
                                setStateOfApp("calendar","false");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: @Rasi I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `View` which is not a part of `Activity`'s content view. So you can't access that view directly.

```
button = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.button_calendar); // will return null
```

This ToggleButton will be null because findViewById will fail to find out ToggleButton in current content view because that view is present in your Adapter not in content view.

And you are getting nullpointerException because you are trying to access property on null view.

```
button.setChecked(true); // This button is null
```

Comment: I am passing the context to the Adapter class and using the same view as my activity class.

Comment: Post code of your ImageAdapter class, or tell me a view which you are inflating in Adapter class.

Comment: Doing that. Just a minute.

Comment: Using a same view never means there reference will be the same. Reference is different. Use Model class and in that pass boolean which will decide whether item is selected or not.

Comment: Google it - you will find many examples. one which I found is. Here you go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339850/how-to-get-a-checkbox-value-using-custom-adapter-and-listview

Comment: Isnt there an easy way to access the same view from my activity class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133855/discussion-between-rasi-and-user2507).

Answer (score 0):

In java we have `<Future>`, but I don't think it's what you're looking for.

The adapter (extending `BaseAdaper`) behaviour lets you create the adapter and, even in a second moment, change underlying data via getAdapter().setData() or whatever method you choose to add.

From this perspective, the adapter is a "stupid" component acting as A View containers, you should retrieve data elsewhere (CursorAdapter is different).

So, in your Activity, fill the adapter with needed data and, when finished, call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(). This will inform the adapter that its own data has changed and it must refresh views

Comment: I tried to use adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() but no success. I have updated my answer to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ideally, the population of the adapter should be coming from the outside.  The adapter should really just take in a list of data and map that data to the views. For example, some method or task in the Activity could produce a list of data (probably asynchronously...since you mentioned it) that you then pass into the adapter and then you can notifyDataSetChanged() if you need to.

I can't see your code, but if for some reason the data is truly required to be populated from inside the adapter, you could use an event bus and subscribe to it in the Activity.  I would recommend going with the first option, but here are some links if you choose to use an event bus:

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding with your question
You are not properly managed the adapter data in your activity.
If any of the data or code interlinked with your adapter data or values
Then you can start those code after you retrieve the values or data and update the view in your activity.
Please note that use Viewholders in adapter to avoid slow populating and scrolling in listviews.
Viewholders will smooth your process.

I personally suggest you that
Please go with Recyclerview and RecyclerViewAdapter. 
So many Android developers are using it.

If you have background tasks in adapter you can prefer to use RX Java or EventBus

If you provide the code
It's better for us to suggest exact solution